# Insertar datos en 1 o 2 tablas, dependiendo el dato que eliga

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo dos tablas:

```
-comerciantes
id (primary key)
id_categoria
nombre

-categoria
id (primary key)
categoria (unique)
```

En un `form` tengo un `option select` con todas las categorías cargadas en la tabla categoría, y al lado de éste, un `input text` para agregar una categoría si esta no existiera, y por último el nombre del comerciante.

Lo que necesito es que, si se elige algún dato del `select`, sólo haga un `insert` en la tabla comerciantes, pero si se agrega una nueva categoría, haga el `insert` en las dos tablas. Pensaba armar un `if`, `if else`, `else` y dependiendo de lo que suceda haga una u otra cosa.

```
<form action="blablabla.php" method ="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre">
  <select name="categoria">
    <?php
     $sql = "select * from categoria";
     $query = mysqli_query($cxn, $sql);
      while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
         echo "<option value =".$r['id'].">".$r['categoria']."</option>";
      };
      ?>
   </select>
   <input type="text" name="nueva_cat">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

y el PHP sería:

```
<?php
include('archivo.php');
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
$nueva_cat = $_POST['nueva_cat'];

if (issset($categoria)) {
  insert en una sola tabla;
}elseif (isset($nueva_cat)) {
 insert en las dos tablas;
}else{
 echo "algo salio mal";
};
?>
```

Comment: Hola, que tal, puedes poner las tablas con sus respectivos campos y tipos? Gracias!

Comment: categoria
id int (11)
categoria varchar (255)

comercientes
id int (11)
id_categoria int(11)
nombre text

Comment: esttaria bien poner algo de codigo, para facilitar las cosas y poder ayudar aunque en si tiene pinta de ser sencillo, más codigo please!, asi no entendemos todos

Comment: Mira como lo hacen los otros usuarios, que muy chulo, y lo mejor, nos enteramos todos. Saludos. (Edita tu pregunta, dale formato, pon tu codigo, comentetanos que has intentado etc...)

Comment: Como lo estás planteando está bien, pero primero comprueba si `$nueva_cat` viene con datos y haces el `insert` en las dos tablas, sino que haga el `insert` en una sola. Puedes usar `isset` o `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

tu lógica es correcta, y como tú mismo lo has propuesto sería una manera de hacerlo:

```
if(!empty($_POST["categoria"])){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO comerciantes (id_categoria, nombre) VALUES ('".$_POST["categoria"]."', '".$_POST["nombre"]."')";
    mysqli_query($conexion, $sql1);
}elseif(!empty($_POST["nueva_cat"])){
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO categoria (categoria) VALUES ('".$_POST["nueva_cat"]."')";
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO comerciantes (id_categoria, nombre) VALUES ('".$_POST["categoria"]."', '".$_POST["nombre"]."')";
    mysqli_query($conexion, $sql1);
    mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
}else{
    echo "No has seleccionado nada";
}
```